# only show button if logged in user meets certain condition react

Tags: reactjs

I have a SQL DB which holds `users` and when they log in their details are passed to react. The user has an `authority` either `USER` or `ADMIN`

I have a component which maps over all the users `UserList`,

```
import React from 'react';
import * as apiCalls from '../api/apiCalls';
import UserListItem from './UserListItem';

class UserList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: undefined,
    page: {
      content: [],
      number: 0,
      size: 9
    }
  };

  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
    console.log(this.loadData);
  }

  loadData = (requestedPage = 0) => {
    apiCalls
      .listUsers({ page: requestedPage, size: this.state.page.size })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          page: response.data,
          loadError: undefined
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ loadError: 'User load failed' });
      });
    };

    onClickNext = () => {
      this.loadData(this.state.page.number + 1);
    };
  
    onClickPrevious = () => {
      this.loadData(this.state.page.number - 1);
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h3 className="card-title m-auto text-center">Members</h3>
        <hr></hr>
        <div className="list-group list-group-flush" data-testid="usergroup">
          <div className="row">
          {this.state.page.content.map((user) => (
              <div key={user.id} className="col-xl-4 col-m-12 mb-4">
              <UserListItem user={user} onClickDeleteMember= { () => {apiCalls.deleteMember(user.id)}} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="clearfix">
          {!this.state.page.first && (
            <span
              className="badge badge-light float-left"
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={this.onClickPrevious}
            ><button className="btn btn-primary">Previous</button></span>
          )}
          {!this.state.page.last && (
            <span
              className="badge badge-light float-right"
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={this.onClickNext}
            >
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
        {this.state.loadError && (
          <span className="text-center text-danger">
            {this.state.loadError}
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```

this calls a `UserListItem` component,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProfileImageWithDefault from '../components/ProfileImageWithDefault'
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';
import * as apiCalls from '../api/apiCalls';


const UserListItem = (props) => {

    // code to display a pop up on delete button click

        

   return (
            <div className="card col-12">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="col-4">
                    <ProfileImageWithDefault
                        className="rounded-circle"
                        alt="profile"
                        width="32"
                        height="32"
                        image={props.user.image}
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 card-title align-self-center mb-0">
                        <h5>{props.user.firstname} {props.user.surname}</h5>
                        <p className="m-0">Society Handicap : {props.user.socHcp}</p>
                        <p className="m-0">Wins : {props.user.wins}</p>
                        <p className="m-0">Home club : {props.user.homeclub}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li className="list-group-item"><i className="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>Email : {props.user.email}</li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><i className="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Mobile : {props.user.mobile}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="float-left btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <Link
                        to={`/${props.user.username}`}>
                            <button  className="btn btn-primary tooltips float-left" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="view"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> </button>
                    </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="float-right btn-group btn-group-m">
                    
                    
                            <button  
                                className="btn btn-secondary tooltips"  
                                onClick={submit}
                                data-placement="top" 
                                data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                data-original-title="Delete">
                                <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    
  );
};

export default UserListItem;
```

within this, I have a delete button which I only want to display if the logged-in user is `ADMIN`

```
<div className="float-right btn-group btn-group-m">


                            <button  
                                className="btn btn-secondary tooltips"  
                                onClick={submit}
                                data-placement="top" 
                                data-toggle="tooltip" 
                                data-original-title="Delete">
                                <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </button>

                    </div>
```

I tried using `props.user.authority === 'ADMIN'  &&`  before the button, which I now realise only shows the delete button if the user being mapped over is ADMIN!

I am now sure how to resolve this so that if the logged-in user is `ADMIN` then all the users on the list will display the delete button.

Comment: In your state of `UserList ` is `user` the logged in user ?

Answer (score 0):

When a user is logged in you can save that user's authority to localStorage.
And get logged user authority in UserListItem component from localStorage.
And render by condition.

Comment: hi, This works, but I dont think it is a suitable solution as the user can edit local storage and effectively make themselves ADMIN....

Comment: if you use jwt token there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have not used JWT yet. Is it simple enough to add onto an existing project.

Comment: It's depend on framework.
If you use django it's simple.